# Monotonicity of the gap of permutated sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, additive-combinatorics, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $a$ be an arbitrary sequence and denote by $\mbox{gap}_k(a) = a_{(k)} - a_{(k+1)}$, where $a_{(k)}$ is the $k$th largest component of $a$. Of course, $k+1$ should be no larger than the length of $a$. Let $b$ be an arbitrary sequence with the same length as $a$. I would like to prove or disprove
$$\mathbb{E} \mbox{gap}_k(\sigma(a) + b) \geq \mbox{gap}_k(a),$$
where $\sigma(\cdot)$ is a uniform permutation operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily true. Set $a=(0,3,4)\;$ and $b=(0,0,2).$ Then possible sequences of the form $\sigma(a)+b\;$ (reordered) are $(0,3,6),$ $(0,4,5)\;$ and $(2,3,4),\;$ so 
$$
  \mathop{\mathbb E}\mathop{\rm gap}\nolimits_2(\sigma(a)+b)=\frac83
    <3=\mathop{\rm gap}\nolimits_2(a).
$$